# Power Query Compressing multiple merge operations

Tags: merge, powerquery

this is likely something simple?

I'm working on a calculated for which I need to bring reference from 4 other tables (vlookup type).  For that I'm using "merge" as an option.

The problem that I have is that I only know how to merge the first two tables and then save the resulting query as another connection and then merge to  the third table, save as connection, etc.  This results in what seems to me a messy and unnecessary number of connections.

I wonder if there's a way in which through the advanced editor I can do all 5 "vlookups" or merge at once.

Thanks a lot[image: Multi Merge]